# Bug in my Ruby version of Tarjan's algorithm

Tags: ruby, tarjans-algorithm

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan's_strongly_connected_components_algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm)

http://en.algoritmy.net/article/44220/Tarjans-algorithm

I can't figure out this bug in my Ruby version of Tarjan's algorithm for strongly connected components. I got the Kosaraju–Sharir algorithm to work, and my Tarjan's algorithm in Ruby works for some graphs. But it does not connect 2 components that should be connected---"10" and "11, 12, 9"

Input file is this directed graph: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/42directed/tinyDG.txt

```
expected: [["1"], ["0", "2", "3", "4", "5"], ["10", "11", "12", "9"], ["6", "8"], ["7"]]
got: [["1"], ["0", "2", "3", "4", "5"], ["10"], ["11", "12", "9"], ["6", "8"], ["7"]]
```

During this final loop, which tries to make a single component, it starts with "10" (last item on stack), but then the current vertex ("parent") also is "10"! This makes the loop cut off "10" as a separate component. Why is the latest item on the stack the same as the parent node? I'd expect "10" only to show up at the END of the component, after we've collected ["12", "11", "9"...then "10"].  Because "10" shows up first, instead of last, we have this problem. How do I fix it?

```
  begin
    last_stack_item = stack.pop
    component << last_stack_item.name
  end while last_stack_item != parent # we're back at the root
```

My Ruby code:

```
    # Tarjan's algorithm to find all strongly connected components (SCCs)
    def scc_tarjan
      index = 0 # numbers nodes consecutively in the order discovered
      stack, scc, vertices = [], [], []

      # create new Struct, if not already defined
      if Struct::const_defined?("TarjanVertex")
        Struct.const_get("TarjanVertex")
      else
        Struct.new("TarjanVertex", :name, :index, :lowlink)
      end

      adj_lists.each do |v|
        # -1 means vertex is unvisited
        vertex = Struct::TarjanVertex.new(v.name, -1, -1)
        vertices << vertex  # array of all TarjanVertex objects in graph
      end
      vertices.each do |vertex|
        tarjan_dfs(vertex, scc, stack, index, vertices) if vertex.index == -1
      end
      # return nested array of all SCCs in graph
      scc
    end

  def tarjan_dfs(parent, scc, stack, index, vertices)
    # Set depth index for vertex to smallest unused index
    parent.index = index
    # lowlink is roughly the smallest index of any node known to be reachable from the vertex
    parent.lowlink = index
    index += 1
    stack << parent
    # loop through all vertices connected to parent
    adj_vertices(parent.name, adj_lists).each do |adj_vertex|
      # since adj_vertices returns array of strings,
      # must convert to TarjanVertex objects
      child = vertices.select {|v| v.name == adj_vertex}.first

      if child.index == -1  # if child vertex not yet visited
        tarjan_dfs(child, scc, stack, index, vertices) # recurse on child

        # change parent's lowlink to smaller lowlink of parent and child)
        parent.lowlink = [parent.lowlink, child.lowlink].min

      # vertex points to earlier (already visited) one in stack,
      # with lower index. thus it's the current SCC
      elsif stack.include?(child)
        parent.lowlink = [parent.lowlink, child.index].min
      end
    end

    # if a vertex's lowlink = its index here, this # cannot go any lower.
    # vertex MUST be root of the SCC.
    if parent.lowlink == parent.index
      component = []  # a single SCC

      # pop off entire SCC, one vertex at a time
      begin
        last_stack_item = stack.pop
        component << last_stack_item.name
      end while last_stack_item != parent # we're back at the root
      scc << component.sort # done with a single SCC
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved my own problem! After going through each loop of my code, with pen and paper, I found that it prematurely went to the bottom component loop at vertex 4. parent.lowlink should NOT equal parent.index at that point. I just had to change 1 word to fix my problem!

I changed "child.index" to "child.lowlink" in the "elsif stack.include?(child)" loop! This correctly dropped 4's lowlink to match that of vertex 6.

Since then parent.lowlink != parent.index, it does not prematurely start making a new component.

Interestingly, my solution is different from all the pseudocode and code online I've found on Tarjan's algorithm, which all says "parent.lowlink = [parent.lowlink, child.index].min"

Instead, I needed "parent.lowlink = [parent.lowlink, child.lowlink].min"

Comment: try this graph: 0->1, 1->2, 2->1, 1->0, 0->3, 3->2. Visit each edge in this particular order, node 2's lowlink will be the same as node 1's index, then node 3's lowlink will also be the same as node 1's index. It will make node 3 as a single component, which is wrong.

Comment: No, I tried your graph. My code has this output: [["0", "1", "2", "3"]]. Your whole graph is 1 single component. My program does not think "3" is a separate single component. My code works. Run it with my one fix---change "child.index" to "child.lowlink"

Comment: Did your program visit each edge in the same order as I gave you? Since this graph is very small, please run your algorithm with pen and paper on it. BTW, have you ever wonder why all the code you found said `parent.lowlink = [parent.lowlink, child.index].min` that different from yours? Why `index`'s value should be different among all nodes? BTW, have you test your program on random generated graphs along with the correct code? If not, why are you so sure you are right? Don't you think that if your solution is different from all the standard solutions, you should consider it twice?

Comment: Just run my Ruby program. You will see it works. Yes, I've tested my code on 13 different graphs, with RSpec. All my tests pass. It gives me the correct SCCs for all 13. My program runs depth-first search and follows the normal preorder of vertices. 

No, it's usually bad object-oriented practice to code with global variables. Developers avoid them most of the time. In all the Java code and pseudocode I saw for Tarjan's algorithm, no one ever used a global variable for index. Also, index needs to be passed in the recursive DFS loop, since it can increment.

Comment: But in code in the two links you gave, variable `index` is a global variable. This is where your code different from them.

Comment: And I feel sorry because I can't run your Ruby program because I don't know how the symbol `adj_list` and `vertices` are defined.

Answer (score -1):

`index` is the timestamp of depth-first-search, it means that every time dfs() reached an unvisited vertex, its value should increase by 1. As a consequence, every nodes' `index` value should be different, and when the algorithm finished, `index`'s value should be equal to the number of vertex in the graph.

But you passed `index` as a parameter to the function `tarjan_dfs`. Since it is passed by value, in dfs() `index += 1` just changed a copy of `index`. As a result, `index` will be the depth of dfs-tree (the tree formed by the spanning of depth-first-search). It's the source of the bug.

So using a global variable `$index` instead of local variable `index` will fix the bug. In fact, all the code listed at the beginning of the question use `index` as a global varibale.

If you don't want to use global variable, and still want to achieve the same effect, you can use a mutable object to wrap it. For example:

- change `index = 0` to `index = {value: 0}`,
- change `parent.index = index` to `parent.index = index[:value]`,
- change `parent.lowlink = index` to `parent.lowlink = index[:value]`,
- change `index += 1` to `index[:value] += 1`.

This is my runnable Ruby implementation, with random graph generator, and it'll compares two procedures' outputs. Just hope it'll be useful.

```
# My version:
def tarjan_scc(adj)
  n = adj.size
  dfn = Array.new(n, -1) # dfn[u] is the timestamp when dfs reached node u
  low = Array.new(n, -1) # low[u] is the lowest index that u or u's children can reach in at most one step
  index = {value: 0}
  stk, sccs = [], []
  (0...n).each do |u|
    tarjan_scc_dfs(adj, u, index, dfn, low, stk, sccs) if dfn[u] == -1
  end
  sccs.sort!
end

def tarjan_scc_dfs(adj, u, index, dfn, low, stk, sccs)
  dfn[u] = low[u] = index[:value]
  index[:value] += 1
  stk.push(u)
  adj[u].each do |v|
    if dfn[v] == -1
      tarjan_scc_dfs(adj, v, index, dfn, low, stk, sccs)
      low[u] = [low[u], low[v]].min
    elsif stk.include?(v)
      low[u] = [low[u], dfn[v]].min
    end
  end
  if dfn[u] == low[u]
    scc = []
    scc << stk.pop while stk[-1] != u
    sccs << scc.push(stk.pop).sort
  end
end


# Test version, with these two changes:
# 1) change Hash `index` to Fixnum `index`
# 2) change `low[u] = [low[u], dfn[v]].min` to `low[u] = [low[u], low[v]].min`
def tarjan_scc_dfs_test(adj, u, index, dfn, low, stk, sccs)
  dfn[u] = low[u] = index
  index += 1
  stk.push(u)
  adj[u].each do |v|
    if dfn[v] == -1
      tarjan_scc_dfs_test(adj, v, index, dfn, low, stk, sccs)
      low[u] = [low[u], low[v]].min
    elsif stk.include?(v)
      low[u] = [low[u], low[v]].min
    end
  end
  if dfn[u] == low[u]
    scc = []
    scc << stk.pop while stk[-1] != u
    sccs << scc.push(stk.pop).sort
  end
end

def tarjan_scc_test(adj)
  n = adj.size
  dfn = Array.new(n, -1)
  low = Array.new(n, -1)
  index = 0
  stk, sccs = [], []
  (0...n).each do |u|
    tarjan_scc_dfs_test(adj, u, index, dfn, low, stk, sccs) if dfn[u] == -1
  end
  sccs.sort!
end


# Randomly generate a simple direct graph with at most max_n nodes
# Nodes are number 0 to max_n - 1. Edges stored adjacent list
def generate_graph(max_n)
  @rng ||= Random.new(Time.hash)
  n = @rng.rand(1..max_n)
  ed = []
  n.times do |i|
    n.times do |j|
      ed << [i, j] if i != j
    end
  end

  ed.size.times do |i|
    j = @rng.rand(i...ed.size)
    ed[i], ed[j] = ed[j], ed[i]
  end

  adj = Array.new(n) { Array.new }
  @rng.rand(0..ed.size).times do |i|
    u, v = ed[i]
    adj[u] << v
  end
  adj
end

# Main loop: generating random graphs and test two functions until answers differ from each other.
while true
  adj = generate_graph(8)
  sccs = tarjan_scc(adj)
  sccs_test = tarjan_scc_test(adj)
  if sccs != sccs_test
    puts "Graph: "
    adj.size.times do |u|
      puts "#{u}: #{adj[u]}"
    end
    puts "Correct components output:"
    p sccs
    puts "Wrong components output by text program:"
    p sccs_test
    break
  end
end
```

**UPDATE:**

This is the steps of your modified algorithm on this test case (as long as I understand your algorithm right):

```
0->1, 1->2, 2->1, 1->0, 0->3, 3->2.
```

```
init: [[index=0, lowlink=0], [index=-1, lowlink=-1], [index=-1, lowlink=-1], [index=-1, lowlink=-1]]
0->1: [[index=0, lowlink=0], [index=1, lowlink=1], [index=-1, lowlink=-1], [index=-1, lowlink=-1]]
1->2: [[index=0, lowlink=0], [index=1, lowlink=1], [index=2, lowlink=2], [index=-1, lowlink=-1]]
2->1: [[index=0, lowlink=0], [index=1, lowlink=1], [index=2, lowlink=1], [index=-1, lowlink=-1]]
(return from node 2, now parent is node 1)
1->0: [[index=0, lowlink=0], [index=1, lowlink=0], [index=2, lowlink=1], [index=-1, lowlink=-1]]
(attention: when visit each edge in this order, node 2's lowlink will be 1, not 0)
(return from node 1, now parent is node 0)
0->3: [[index=0, lowlink=0], [index=1, lowlink=0], [index=2, lowlink=1], [index=1, lowlink=1]]
3->2: [[index=0, lowlink=0], [index=1, lowlink=0], [index=2, lowlink=1], [index=1, lowlink=1]]
(node 2's lowlink is 1, so node 3's lowlink will not be 0, and node 3 will be marked as a single SCC)
(return from node 3, now parent is node 0)
(mark [0, 1, 2] as a SCC)
```

As you see, the order of edge-visiting will make different answers. But it should not matter in tarjans-algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for trying, but your comment is not correct. It's necessary to pass "index" inside the recursive loop, because it needs to increment. It represents the first level (depth) at which we find each vertex.

I solved my problem! After going through each loop of my code, with pen and paper, I found that it prematurely went to the bottom component loop at vertex 4. parent.lowlink should NOT equal parent.index at that point.

I just had to change 1 word to fix my problem! I changed "child.index" to "child.lowlink" in the "elsif stack.include?(child)" loop! This correctly changed 4's lowlink.

Comment: I believe if you change `index` into a global variable `$index` (do you know prefix `$` marks a global variable in Ruby?), it can also increment. What's better, its increment won't lose after function returns.